# Trouble importing tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables, anaconda, system-administration

I installed and ran Docker for image classification and everything was fine till I had to retrain my model, I used the code                                     `Python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \` and at first the error was not being able to import tensorflow, but I had correctly installed tensorflow through pip3 and it was running fine in the python shell, so I deleted Python 27 from the path as I think it was being redirected there somehow, but I still have the anaconda version of python 27, and the error that pops up right now is

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try 
Python `tensorflow\examples\image_retraining\retrain.py \`

Comment: Nah doesn't work.